# Rails API Routing Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have the following specified in my Rails Routes.  I want to allow both **GET** and **POST** on this route, but whatever I try, it only allows the #index action, and doesn't access the #create action when a POST is requested.

```
match ':user_id/special_deals', to: 'special_deals#index'
```

I've tried this too:

```
match ':user_id/special_deals', to: 'special_deals#index', :via => [:get, :post]
```

I need the User ID to be specified first since people with access to the API can access multiple User's info.

Answer (score 1):

It is working exactly as you asked it to do. If you want `POST` to routed to `create` action here are your route configs:

```
match ':user_id/special_deals', to: 'special_deals#index', :via => [:get]
match ':user_id/special_deals', to: 'special_deals#create', :via => [:post]
```

There are simpler ways of writing these but I just wanted to use the same format you wrote it. Please check [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to know about them.

If you already have a `User` controller, you can write more structured routes like:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :special_deals, :only => [:index, :create]
end
```

This will make routes for special_deals like (#shows where it will be routed to):

```
GET /users/:user_id/special_deals  #special_deals#index
POST /users/:user_id/special_deals  #special_deals#create
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you HungryCode.